# Split with different delimiters JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, split

Lets say I have this kind of data:

> "IAB98D Daewoo Cielo 15487964 PARABRISAS TRA"
>
> "TAI64A Fiat Siena 13283191 PARACHOQUE DEL-CAPOT"
>
> "RAD34B Toyota Corolla 11934274 TECHO-PUERTA TRA IZQ"

Where: 1st element = the car's ID - 2nd element = brand of the car - 3rd element = model of the car - 4th element = owner's ID - 5th element and beyond separated by a "-" are the damaged parts of the car

Thing is when I use .split(" ") works fine for the first fourth elements but in the damaged parts is where things gets tricky for example in this 2nd array part "PARACHOQUE DEL-CAPOT" that means there are 2 damaged parts "PARACHOQUE DEL" and "CAPOT" if I use .split(" ") it will separate "PARACHOQUE DEL" to "PARACHOQUE" and "DEL" and I don't want that to happen because that's just 1 damaged part is there any way to achieve this? or any recommendations? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please show us how you “use .split(" ")”. How do you handle brands like Alfa Romeo?

Comment: Oh the 1st answer helped me out, that data came from a .class used in an exam from my college but all the brands were all just 1 word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this with 2 calls to `split`, the first one limiting the fields to `5` fields: the first 4 fields and the damaged parts.

The first call to split is the [two-arg overload of `split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-), with a limit.

This code takes advantage of the fact that limiting the fields piles the remaining part of the original string, even if there are more separators, into the last element.

```
String line = "TAI64A Fiat Siena 13283191 PARACHOQUE DEL-CAPOT";
String[] fields = line.split("\\s+", 5);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(fields));
```

This will generate the 5 fields for you:

```
[TAI64A, Fiat, Siena, 13283191, PARACHOQUE DEL-CAPOT]
```

The second call to split is the [one-arg overload of `split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-).
Then you can `split` the last element on `"-"` to extract the damaged parts.

```
String damaged = fields[4];
String[] parts = damaged.split("-");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This outputs:

```
[PARACHOQUE DEL, CAPOT]
```

You will need to ensure that there are really 5 elements in the `fields` array before using index `4`.